# Ethernet not detected whatsoever

Tags: lubuntu, ethernet

I recently installed Lubuntu 13.04 64-bit on one of my older computers (the computer is ancient - DDR1, no USB boot, yet it's 64-bit. Go figure.)

Anyway, the Wi-Fi adapter I tried to use malfunctioned very quickly, and, after a bit of troubleshooting, I gave up (for the time being.) I decided to try and get the built-in ethernet working. The Lubuntu box is wired via Ethernet to a computer running Windows XP, which is connected to Wi-Fi and is set to share it. Trouble is, Windows says the ethernet cable is unplugged, and the computer running Lubuntu is entirely oblivious to the existence of its Ethernet port. `lspci | grep -i eth` returns *absolutely nothing*, so I can't even put the correct firmware on a USB stick and install it that way.

What's wrong? I will provide any computer/OS/BIOS/etc details requested.

UPDATE: Found out why Lubuntu wasn't recognizing the Ethernet - the BIOS had Onboard LAN disabled. I enabled it, but now the tray icon says "Ethernet - device not managed", and `sudo ifup eth0` starts spamming a bunch of stuff about DHCP, and the command never finishes.

Comment: Post the output of `lspci -nn` and `lshw -C network`

Comment: @grimpitch http://pastebin.com/ZmP8MGNG

Comment: Is it unplugged? It says the link is down. Try another driver: `sudo rmmod 8139too && sudo modprobe 8139cp`

Comment: @grimpitch `rmod` was an invalid command, but `sudo modprobe -r 8139too` seemed to work. Adding the module `8139cp` didn't fix it, though - the network tray icon now says "no network devices available", and running ifdown and ifup doesn't work - ifup says "could not configure hardware" or something like that.

Comment: It's not the the right driver for the adapter then. First run `mii-tool eth0 -F 10baseT-FD` then remove `8139cp` and reload `8139too`.

Comment: Running mii-tool while `8139cp` was still loaded said it couldn't find interface eth0, but after loading `8139too` running mii-tool exited with no output (and no effect.) I've already tried ifup/downing the enterface, and ifup eth0 still doesn't exit cleanly while running `8139too`. However, even though the command never exited, I can still close the terminal. mii-tool only exits cleanly after ifup-ing eth0 while running 8139too. So I have no ideas. :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8909/discussion-between-grimpitch-and-jamestheawesomedude)

Comment: I can't log into chat for some reason, but `sudo mii-tool -v` says 10 Mbit, Full Duplex, No link. ifup says interface already configured, and the tray icon still says "Ethernet network | device not managed".

Answer (score 2):

Look into `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change the line `managed=false` to `managed=true` then restart `network-manager`:

`sudo service network-manager restart`