# Visual bug after restarting NetworkManager.service Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: lubuntu

I'm just a novice on linux so please take it light.
I was testing out on how to connect two pc through lan following the instruction from [Ethernet not detected whatsoever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299238/ethernet-not-detected-whatsoever).

After editing **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf** and setting **managed=true**, I restarted the service by running **sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service** .

After restarting, these weird icons of the ethernet and wifi started appearing on the right side of my screen and they won't go away.
[image]

I tried rebooting the system but they kept reappearing. I undid the change to the NetworkManager.conf but the visual bug is still there. This only happened right after I ran the restart command and I can't figure out why. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've tried doing what you suggested to a *jammy* (22.04) system here, and I had no issue like what you describe, and cannot think of any reason to experience what you have, given what you describe doing.  Did you make any other changes before that?  (*I wonder if you changed `~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf` for example; I'd likely look inside that file to look for any non `alignment=left` or `alignment=right` for example but adding the contents of that file for us to look at may help us to come up with ideas; ie. add `cat ~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf` to your question please)

Comment: thanks for the response. The only thing I did before that was change the system name using `hostnamectl set-hostname` and installing NoMachine. At the end of the day, since this was a new install, I decided it was faster to reinstall a new image of lubuntu rather than debugging the problem.